# How do I detach a process from the command prompt?

Tags: shell, react-native, command-prompt

I can't find the answer to this question anywhere online and it seems like it should be super simple. I'm a beginner trying to run react-native on a virtual device, so I start by making the virtual device by running

```
android avd
```

Which opens the virtual device manager and then I can start my virtual device. But then I can't do anything else in the command prompt! I can't close it either or else the virtual device will close. What's the next step here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My smart CS friend helped me. Instead of `android avd`, you should run `start android avd`.

Comment: And if you don't want another command prompt window to open up, it should be

"start /b android avd"